# Why is DataReader giving “Enumeration Yielded No Results”?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader, datareader

My SQL db stored proc returns results but datareader shows “Enumeration Yielded No Results”?

this is my code:

```
var sqlFastProd = String.Format("Getnpidataforencryption");
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
                {
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlFastProd, conn);
                    myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartingId", startId));
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@countOfRecords", CountofRecords));
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    List<DataElement> dataElements = new List<DataElement>();
                    var recordsFetchTime = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan t = serviceStartTime - recordsFetchTime;
                                       if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                        …
                        }
                    }
                 }
```

Stored proc

CREATE PROCEDURE Getnpida

```
taforencryption @StartingId     BIGINT,--1       
                                         @countOfRecords BIGINT -- 101       
AS       
  BEGIN       
      SELECT textid,       
             originaltextdata as textdata,       
             keyname       
      FROM   npidataencryption       
      WHERE IsEncrypted is null and id BETWEEN @StartingId AND @countOfRecords      
  END 

need help, thanks in adv
```

ance:)

Answer (score 2):

That's cause mostly your stored procedure returned no data with those input values. You might want to check if the reader has any rows using the `HasRows` property

```
if(!reader.HasRows)
{
    // return empty response model
}
```

Well looks like you are already checking for rows as in below (from your posted code). Then in that case, I believe surely you are getting that error from debugger while debugging

```
if (reader.HasRows)
 {
   while (reader.Read())
```

if that's not the case then you should post your procedure code as well to gain more insight.

Comment: Stored proc is returning data, Hasrow is also true, but when I see the result view it does not have any data there.  shows ? in each row.

Comment: it skips the while loop had there is no data, but strange thing is hasrows is true, I don't understand

Comment: If hasrows is true and it is skipping the if(hasrows) the code in the question is different from what you are executing.

Comment: No it not skipping if(reader.hasrow), since hasrow is true it goes inside, but while (reader.read() is fasle hence it is exiting the while loop.

Comment: weirdest thing is I was executing the same code from past 3 week it was working fine, but today I modified the connection string, and pointing to different db, the connection string is correct and the connection is open without any error. conn.open() is true